# Postgresql Procedure not getting called from JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-9.1

I am working with postgresql procedures and trying to call a procedure from my JDBC program. But getting runtime exception saying procedure doesn't exist eventhough I cross-checked and verified that the procedure name is correct.
This is what I am doing

```
 CallableStatement   cs = connection.prepareCall("{call proc1()}");
 cs.executeUpdate();
```

And here's my proc1 procedure

```
   create or replace procedure proc1()
as

begin

insert into employee_info values(1,'johnny','1111',43);
-----

end
```

This is what the output is

```
   Connection Failed! ERROR: function proc1() does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I dont understand why its not working eventhough proc1() exists in database.
And what should i Cast?

Comment: there is no `create or replace procedure` in Postgres

Comment: oh.Is it? Then how should I create procedure. Actually I am familiar with mysql , oracle and other databases. and i am new to postgres..Can you direct me to a good link which explains postgresql procedures

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No. The procedure is working fine when I execute it manually in database. So nothing wrong with procedure syntax.

Comment: Then you are not using Postgres. Postgres does not have procedures, only functions, and thus it only has a `create or replace function` statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Howcome. Its getting executed here. I am using postgres. Once try the same code yourself if you have postgres installed on your system. It will get execute..

Comment: I **have** Postgres on my system and it does **not** accept a `create procedure` statement. You will get a `ERROR: syntax error at or near "procedure" Position: 19 [SQL State=42601]`. Have a look at the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html

Comment: But i am able to execute. I am using pgAdmin Tool.

Comment: Strange part is that. Now I am able to execute the procedure from the JDBC program when I modify CallableStatement to just Statement statement.execute("{call proc1()}"); is working

Comment: `create procedure` is a syntax accepted by [PostgresPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgres-plus/info), a postgres fork aimed at oracle compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution. The main problem was with JDBC Driver which I downloaded from the official [website](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html). I was using the 
postgresql driver. I dont know what's wrong with it but It seems like it is not supporting proedures. So I switched to EnterpriseDB(EDB) driver. Now the same program works fine and procedures are getting executed.

I just made these changes 
1)Changing Driver 
2)Changing Driver Class url from `"org.postgresql.Driver"` to `"com.edb.Driver"`
3)Dabase url   `"jdbc:postgresql://host:port/db` to `"jdbc:edb://host:port/db"`

That's all. Now the procedures works too.

Comment: While this may have circumvented your problem, this answer is not really correct. The "standard" JDBC driver for PostgreSQL supports procedures perfectly well. In [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org), we've been running integration tests for PostgreSQL for ages now. It's probably due to your "procedure" having been created through PostgresPlus, I believe? It would be great to have an updated answer if you still know what the real problem was.

Answer (score 2):

Add correct schema name to callable statement and it shall work. Please refer to below code for example.

```
CallableStatement   cs = connection.prepareCall("{call yoursSchema.proc1()}");
```